# Azure Stream analytics how to write window function when getting the data from different devices and all devices have diff fields/properties

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have telemetry coming to IOT hub from 16 devices and all devices are of different types. I want to apply window function to get the average of the last 10mins data. Since each device will have very different parameters I am unable to define a query. The device parameters are

```
Voltage L1
Voltage L2
Voltage L3
Current L1
Current L2
Current L3
Power
Consumer Energy
Main_Tank_Oil_Level
Calibration_Level
Temperature
Actual Pressure
Actual_Flow
Main_Tank_Oil_Level
Calibration_Level
Temperature
Actual Pressure
Oil_Flow
```

and each device have multiple parameters.

How do we apply window function in such scenario

Comment: Hey there, do they all share a common metric you want to average, or do you want 1 record every 10 minutes that get the average of all metrics, regardless of the device? Could you please share what the output should look like?

Comment: Hi @FlorianEiden , The requirement is to find avg for each fields for each device. so if the device 1 has 2 fields temp , pressure and device 2 has oil flow pressure , hydraulic level , then we need to find avg for each property per device.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I understand you actually have multiple logical pipelines, inside a single physical stream. You have multiple device types, requiring each a different Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) query. They all share the same input event/iot hub.

There are 3 approaches here.

**1 - Multiple ASA jobs**

You can create multiple ASA jobs, all reading from the same source event/iot hub. Each one will have a different query addressing a specific device type. The first step of each query will be to filter the stream to look only at the device type they're scoped on (`WHERE deviceType = 1` or `WHERE VoltageL1 IS NOT NULL`).

They will have a different output schema. So you can either target a single output across them, but it will need to be a "schema-less" service like event hub, cosmos db, storage account... Or you can output to different destinations if you're targeting a strongly typed storage component (different tables in a SQL database).

The key here is to define and use a different [consumer groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups) for each ASA jobs in the event hub.

**2 - Single job, independent queries**

To reduce cost, and if the volume of data allows it, you can put all your queries into a single ASA job. It will look something like this:

```
--- This step concentrates reads on the input source to reduce consumer group exhaustion
WITH SingleSource AS (
   SELECT * FROM MyInput
)

SELECT
   DeviceId, 
   DeviceType,
   System.Timestamp() AS WindowEndtime,
   AVG(VoltageL1) as AvgVoltageL1,
   AVG(VoltageL2) as AvgVoltageL2
INTO MyOutput
FROM SingleSource
WHERE DeviceType = 1 -- (or something like VoltageL1 IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY DeviceId, DeviceType, TUMBLINGWINDOW(minute,10)

SELECT
   DeviceId, 
   DeviceType,
   System.Timestamp() AS WindowEndtime,
   AVG(Main_Tank_Oil_Level) as AvgMain_Tank_Oil_Level,
   AVG(Calibration_Level_Temperature) as AvgCalibration_Level_Temperature
INTO MyOutput
FROM SingleSource
WHERE DeviceType = 2 -- (or something like Main_Tank_Oil_Level IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY DeviceId, DeviceType, TUMBLINGWINDOW(minute,10)

...
```

That's if you want to output everything into the same destination (`MyOutput` here). Same as for multiple jobs, you can always create multiple outputs and vary the `INTO` clause.

**3 - Single job, conforming query**

If you also want to process the data so everything fits on a single schema, you can add a final step to do so:

```
--- This step concentrates reads on the input source to reduce consumer group exhaustion
WITH SingleSource AS (
   SELECT * FROM MyInput
),

Type1 AS (
   SELECT
      DeviceId, 
      DeviceType,
      System.Timestamp() AS WindowEndtime,
      AVG(VoltageL1) as AvgVoltageL1,
      AVG(VoltageL2) as AvgVoltageL2
   INTO MyOutput
   FROM SingleSource
   WHERE DeviceType = 1 -- (or something like VoltageL1 IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY DeviceId, DeviceType, TUMBLINGWINDOW(minute,10)
),

Type2 AS (
   SELECT
      DeviceId, 
      DeviceType,
      System.Timestamp() AS WindowEndtime,
      AVG(Main_Tank_Oil_Level) as AvgMain_Tank_Oil_Level,
      AVG(Calibration_Level_Temperature) as AvgCalibration_Level_Temperature
   INTO MyOutput
   FROM SingleSource
   WHERE DeviceType = 2 -- (or something like Main_Tank_Oil_Level IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY DeviceId, DeviceType, TUMBLINGWINDOW(minute,10)
),
...
AllRecords AS (
   SELECT DeviceId, DeviceType,WindowEndtime, AvgVoltageL1, AvgVoltageL2, NULL AS AvgMain_Tank_Oil_Level, NULL AS AvgCalibration_Level_Temperature FROM Type1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DeviceId, DeviceType,WindowEndtime, NULL AS AvgVoltageL1, NULL AS AvgVoltageL2, AvgMain_Tank_Oil_Level, AvgCalibration_Level_Temperature FROM Type2
...
)

SELECT * INTO MyOutput FROM AllRecords
```

That's the best option if you share some common metrics and need to put that into a single SQL table.